# "Cannot read property 'avatarURL' of null" error

Tags: javascript

Just like to point out i am relatively new to Javascript so i don't know a lot forgive me if this is an easy fix :/

I recently added an author variable to my Discord music Bot which should (in theory) show the profile picture of the user who executes the play command, i did this by using this small line of code `icon_url: client.user.avatarURL` and i am running into an error where upon some googling is due to me not being logged into discord.js? If this is the only issue i am facing then i would really appreciate some help on how to login to discord.js

Comment: Welcome to the JS world! Your error means, that the user is null. Did you look at the [login docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=login)

Comment: I am aware i need to login but that website is really complex and i don't know how to actually login so "avatarURL" will work

[EDIT: it says to use "  client.login('token')  " but doing so results in the bot not working, stating "client not defined"

Comment: Did you try to create a new client with `const client = new Discord.Client();`?

Answer (score 0):

In v12 its `client.user.avatarURL()`